# Does the content I post on additional Tumblr pages of one account, show up on the dashboard of my followers?

Tags: tumblr

For example, I have a blog and have recently added an extra page. If I post things on this extra page, will those following my main blog have it come up in their newsfeed? Or do they have to follow the page separately?

Comment: Do you mean you added a new blog or a new page to your current blog?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to **custom pages**: No, followers don't get notified if you create or edit a custom page. You'd usually use such pages for "static" content, like "About me" or "Contact".

If you are referring to **additional blogs**: No, followers of your main blog don't get notified if you create or update a secondary blog. They'd need to follow this blog separately.